# How to make custom data validation that works with formula?

Tags: excel, validation, warnings

im trying to incorporate data validation into my sheet however it does not work when the cell im trying to put it on contains a formula

for example

cell A1 = "=A2" where A2 is just a number 5,

cell B1 = "=B2" where B2 is also the number 5

Basically, i want to have a warning when cell A1 is not equal to cell B2.

under data validation i input the following on cell B1
settings: custom, checkbox ignore blanked checked, formula = "=A1<>B1".

Error Alert: warning, title: "testtitle", error message: "test message", checkbox show error alert checked

when i change the value in B2 from 5 to 6, i should expect a warning but it did not happen.

how can i modify this to make this work?

thanks

Comment: I don't think so. If I'm, not mistaken, the validation is made when you manually change the cell value or formula. In this case, the formula is changing the cell value, not you. As a workaround you could put the validation in B2 cell as "A2<>B2"

Comment: unfortunately, doing that will defeat the purpose of incorporating data validation with formulas